# In memory Service Bus (NServiceBus)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, nservicebus

I was wondering if there is a way, through configuration, to put NServiceBus into a mode that writes messages to an in memory queue instead of a physical queue?

My use case is `Integration testing`. Ideally I would like to avoid placing the messages on a physical queue to avoid a dependency on the queue from the integration tests. My tests are focused on testing the logic around the code that puts messages on the bus, but the tests will fail if the queue doesn't exist.

Right now I am manually creating the queue in the test, but would like to avoid that.

Whenever I do a `bus.Send(queueMessageObject);` I would like for the message to just be stored in memory (or perhaps just be ignored since I am just testing the logic that puts it there).

In my `unit tests` I am able to get around this by mocking the IBus object using MOQ. However in my integration tests I am not mocking the bus and would like to send the messages to an in memory endpoint. I would also prefer to not use a different api than `bus.Send()` for placing the messages on the bus.

Is there a current/future NServiceBus config setting that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we are planning to support it, see https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1357

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that we may have some variation on bus.UseTransport<MyCustomTransport> to configure a custom endpoint ?

Comment: Yes you could say that, so we would have a InMemoryTransport

Answer (score 1):

> I would also prefer to not use a different api than bus.Send() for placing the messages on the bus.

Why not? Having your own abstraction that is implemented with NServiceBus lets you have a bunch of other implementations and/or switching between different buses easily.

We have a parametrized factory that returns one of few implementations, messages can be placed in a log, written to files, sent over wcf etc. This lets us create a lot of different unit/integration tests.

Comment: I agree there are multiple ways to abstract this using my own layer. There is no question about the usefulness of that in general.  However  this is an existing codebase with many bus.Send() calls. I am just curious if it's technically possible to do this. I also see some value in running this through the same configuration as my production code path - without skipping over it through abstraction.

Comment: The 4.0 supports so called In Memory Bus, however the publising api seems to be different than regular publishing http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/1108963-using-the-in-memory-bus

Comment: Yes, I found this API earlier, but I was hoping to not have to route my calls through this :-) I guess this might be the only NServiceBus based solution to this scenario, so it's probably not possible to do what I am trying to do.